# How to have multiple server (sapper) get, post, etc routes in a single file?

Tags: svelte

I am using sapper server routing and this works with individual .js files that will handle a single get, post, etc using the filename as the route and export function post(req,res,next).

I would like to use my own server routing like Express with multiple handlers in a single file like...

app.post('/api/abc', req,res,next)

app.post('/api/def', req,res,next)

Is this possible in Sapper and if so can someone please give an example?

Answer (score 7):

Add the handlers to your [server.js](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template/blob/master/src/server.js):

```js
polka() // Or `express()`, if you're using that

    /* add your handlers here */
    .post('/api/abc', (req, res, next) => {...})
    .post('/api/def', (req, res, next) => {...})

    /* normal stuff */
    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Rich Harris I would like to add that this is only true when `"polka": "next"` is installed in `package.json`, which currently evaluates via `npm ls polka` to `polka@1.0.0-next.11`. The  `^0.5.2` wich looks like latest stable version is returning 404 to every route defined this way. In other words, as soon as I put polka version number into package.json, I can only define routes in a clean sapper `^0.27.9` via route pages/server routes.