# Axios throwing 404 error on POST request although express route exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, svelte, sapper

I am creating a sveltejs/sapper app. I am trying to post some info from the frontend to the backend express server using axios in the script tag. Although get requests from external sources are succeeding, axios is throwing a 404 error while posting to the express route. Refer these images posted below.

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
import sirv from 'sirv';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';

const app = express();

const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';

app.use(
 sirv('static', {dev}),
 sapper.middleware(),
 bodyParser.json(),
 bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})
);

app.post('/task', (req, res) => {
        res.sendStatus(200);
 console.log(req.body);
 // fs.writeFile(`./downloads/${req.body.file}`, req.body.buffer, (err) => {
 //  if (err) throw err;
 //  console.log(`${res.file} downloaded to backend server`);
 // });
});

app.listen(PORT, err => {
 if (err) console.log('error', err);
});
```

**frontend script**

```js
<script>
 //variables
 let start = false;
    let url = '';
    let filename = '';
    let downloadProgress = 0;
    let error = false;
    let progressBarStyle = 'bg-success';
    //automated Events
    $:downloadLabel = downloadProgress.toString();
    $:if(downloadLabel == '100') {
        progressBarStyle = 'bg-warning';
        downloadLabel = 'DOWNLOAD COMPLETE! FILE WILL BE TRANSFERED SHORTLY!';
    }
    //axios config
    let config = {
    onDownloadProgress: progressEvent => {
    downloadProgress = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total); }
    }
 //functions
 function startDownload() {
        start = true;
  axios.get(url, config).then((res) => {
         if(res.status == 200) {
                let data = {
                    file: filename,
                    buffer: res.data
                }
                axios.post('/task', data).then(() => {
                    console.log('Data sent to server');
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
            else {
                error = true;
            }
  }).catch((err) => {
            error = true;
  });
 }
    function reset() {
        // start = false;
        // url = '';
        // filename = '';
        // downloadProgress = 0;
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

**browser console**
[image: browser console]

**network tab**
[image: network tab]

Comment: It would be more beneficially if you could add the code with text vs images

Comment: In the server script, you are not sending anything back. You have to send something.

Comment: @Matthew Done! I've edited my post

Comment: I see you writing a file on your backend, but not sending any response back to the front-end.  I think you need to do a res.send() to get feedback on client side.

Comment: @Maiya Well the writing of the file has been commented out. Axios is not even able to send the request to the server side, otherwise there would have been a browser log saying "Data sent to server"

Comment: Ok, but it's not the actual writing of the file that is important.  The first thing would be to make sure you are sending something back to the client at all.  Did you do that?

Comment: If I were trouble-shooting it, I would temporarily take out the static routing, to see if that makes a difference.  Is it getting caught up in there ; and I would try pasting the whole url in the post request, port and all, to see if that makes a difference.  Not sure if that will help, but just a couple ideas .. to see if it gives any clues.

Comment: @Maiya Yes I tried sending a response as well as a response status from the server, but the error still persists. Sapper says the static route is important for overall working of the app (that code was already present in the basic template). But I'll still experiment & break some things up to see what happens.

Comment: I've editted the server code to reflect suggestions (responding with status 200 to the client)

Answer (score 2):

You use `sapper`,
Try to read [docs](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs/).

example:

```
const express = require('express');
import sirv from 'sirv';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';

const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const app = express();

app

    /* add your handlers here */
    .post('/task', (req, res, next) => {
        res.sendStatus(200);
        console.log(req.body);
    })

    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

I find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751156/how-to-have-multiple-server-sapper-get-post-etc-routes-in-a-single-file) solution

Comment: I am using axios in the script tag of my markup. So I guess the framework is not playing a huge role here. And I've tried reading the docs. The sapper community is still very small & hence there wasnt much help there.

Comment: How can you answer in like that? is outside the topic even for a comment, stack overflow is about helping each other, if you read the docs, as you suggested for the solution, how about next thing you type is the real fix to the problem.

Comment: I I don't have reputation to leave a comment @SilentTremor.

Comment: That's something else, let's help each-other!

Answer (score 0):

You have to send something in the request handler:

```
(req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

Comment: I did that, but that doesnt make any difference. Seems like axios cant find the route.